# Bootstrap and HTML5 tag structure semantics

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup

I am coding a site using bootstrap and html5 boilerplate together and I am trying to structure it in the most semantic valid way possible.

so my page is pretty simple it consists of a header, a section with two columns, and a footer.

I am wondering which of the ways below is the best way to structure things semantically for example the section and footer parts of the page.

```
<div class="row">
   <section>
      ....
   </section>
<div class="row">
   <footer>
     ....
   </footer>
</div>



<section>
   <div class="row">
     ...
   </div>
</section>
<footer>
   <div class="row">
     ....
   </div>
</footer>


<section class="row">
  ...
</section>
<footer class="row">
  ...
</footer>
```

Comment: It really depends on what your content is.

Comment: the answer by Jules is spot on, you don't want two 'rows' for your section(s) when you talk about two columns. you'll want `<header></header>` too, you could possibly add an `<aside></aside>` depending on what is in your columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last one:

```
<section class="row">
  ...
</section>
<footer class="row">
  ...
</footer>
```

The `row` class is presentational.

Comment: I should probably also add that Bootstrap (whilst being absolutely brilliant), will force you to write a fair amount of presentational HTML/CSS - especially when it comes to forms. Remember that semantic markup is an ideal - i.e. something to strive for, not a hard and fast rule.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<article>` tags for the main content. If both of the columns contain article content, then you can use `<section>`s to separate the columns.

```
<article>
  <section id="part-1">
    <header class="section-header">...</header>
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="part-2">
    <header class="section-header">...</header>
    ...
  </section>
</article>
<footer id="main-footer">
  ...
</footer>
```

And then add as many `<div>`s as you need as hooks for the CSS.

Don't use class names that refer to a specific visual rendering, such as "row". Instead, use classes (and IDs) that refer to the content, such as "part-1" and "main-footer".